# Screen Reader reading disabled button's AutomationProperty.Id

Tags: c#, wpf, button, accessibility, screen-readers

I've added a simple WPF window with two buttons in it.
The buttons are made visible by a certain logic and have bindings which change their `Visibility` and `IsEnabled` properties.
Now, I'm testing with windows navigator and seeing that the default windows navigator is reading about the buttons even when they are not visible.
How should I make the button not read by Screen Readers (or windows default navigator) when the button is disabled or not visible?

```
<Button Margin="0,0,80,10" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="failedButton" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" DataContext="{Binding InstallationViewModel}" 
        Command="{Binding Failed}" 
        Visibility="{Binding Failed, 
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Content="Failed?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Automation api reads everything that provide a automation peer. So if you don't want your ui element expose to automation clients, you need to override `OnCreateAutomationPeer` and return `null`. And that means, you choose either support automation or not, but you can't change it at runtime.

Comment: Along with your suggestion, for runtime changes can't I use the `RaisePropertyChanged` as shown in this example [CodeProjectExample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/172391/UIAutomation-Coded-UI-Tests-AutomationPeer-and-WPF.aspx?msg=3871872) to change what element has automation enabled or not?